# Comparing strings with key values

Tags: strings

How can I match key value as a string for `Large` ?  The call `\fupTfr [tsz=Large, grp=true, nkb=Title]` does not actually print anything.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N   \l_fup_tsz_tl    % Type Size
\bool_new:N \l_fup_grp_bool  % Grouping
\tl_new:N   \l_fup_nkb_tl    % Title

\keys_define:nn { fup_tfr_keys }
  {
    tsz .tl_set:N = \l_fup_tsz_tl,
    tsz .initial:n = {Large},
    tsz .default:n = {Large},
    tsz .usage = general,

    grp .bool_set:N = \l_fup_grp_bool,
    grp .initial:n = false,
    grp .default:n = false,
    grp .usage = general,

    nkb .tl_set:N = \l_fup_nkb_tl,
    nkb .initial:n = ,
    nkb .default:n = ,
    nkb .usage = general,
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\fupTfr} { O{} }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { fup_tfr_keys } { #1 }

    \str_case:nn {\l_fup_tsz_tl}
      {
        {Large}
                 {
                   \bool_if:NTF {\l_fup_grp_bool}
                     { \group_begin: \Large \l_fup_nkb_tl \group_end: }
                         { \Large }
                 }

        {default}  { \l_fup_nkb_tl }
      }
  }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fupTfr [tsz=Large, grp=true, nkb=Title]

\end{document}
```

Comment: please follow the expl3 naming scheme. All your command names are missing the module part.

Comment: Fixed as instructed.

Comment: you need `\str_case:on`. And `\l_fup_tsz_tl` should probably be a string variable and not a tl variable.

Comment: That does the job.  What is the reason behind `:on` ?

Comment: see chapter 4 in expl3.pdf and chapter 1 of interface3.pdf and

Comment: Why would I need an expansion once ?

Comment: Because you want the string test to compare the contents of the tl/str variable, not its literal name.

Comment: Or maybe `\str_case:Vn \l_fup_tsz_tl { … }` resp. `\str_case:Vn \l_fup_tsz_str { … }`

Comment: Are there advantages of `\str_case:Vn` over `\str_case:on` ?